# Objective c - pass back string value using delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, delegates

I want to pass UITextField *nameText from GreenViewController to UILabel *nameValue in ViewController using delegate.

I made delegate, the onSave method in ViewController is called but the screen is not going back and the name is not passed.
What is the problem?
Here are the header and impelentation files:

GreenViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol GreenViewDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)onSave:(NSString*)nameValue;

@end


@interface GreenViewController : UIViewController

@property id<GreenViewDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic) NSString* sliderValuePassed;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *Next;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *Save;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *Back;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *sliderTextValue;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *NameText;

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender;

@end
```

GreenViewController.m

```
#import "GreenViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface GreenViewController ()

@end

@implementation GreenViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.sliderTextValue.text = self.sliderValuePassed;
}
- (IBAction)back:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate onSave:self.NameText.text];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GreenViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <GreenViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *slider;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *sliderTextValue;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *EnterName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *NameValue;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *LikeIOS;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *CheckboxIOS;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "RedViewController.h"
#import "GreenViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.sliderTextValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Slider value = %d",(int)self.slider.value];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"yellowToGreen"]){
        GreenViewController* gVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        gVC.sliderValuePassed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Slider value = %d",(int)self.slider.value];
        gVC.delegate = self;
    }else if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"yellowToRed"]){
        RedViewController* rVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        rVC.sliderValuePassed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Slider value = %d",(int)self.slider.value];
        rVC.CheckboxIOS = self.CheckboxIOS;
    }
}

- (IBAction)sliderChangeValue:(id)sender {
    int sliderVal = self.slider.value;
    self.sliderTextValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Slider value = %d",sliderVal];
}

-(void)onSave:(NSString*)nameValue{
    NSLog(@"onSave in father controller");
    self.NameValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name = %@",nameValue];
}

@end
```

Comment: where did you set the delegate ?

Comment: This is all my code, and not setting the delegate might be my problem. 
I didn't know how to do it and where to write it. I will be glad for you help @Mr.T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you didnt set the delegate .

Set it like this:

```
  GreenViewController *myVc = [[GreenViewController alloc] init];

  myVc.delegate = self;
```

Put this in your view controller view did load method!!!

Comment: I did it when i wait for an answer (found your code on internet), but somehow the program not reach the onSave method in ViewController.
It doesn't print on console:    NSLog(@"onSave in father controller");
@Mr.T

Comment: how you move back to view controller ? do you press on back button  to move from greenview to view controller ?

Comment: i press the save button that is connected to save method on GreenViewController with outlet. This method is on my code in GVC.m @Mr.T

Comment: I added: " gVC.delegate = self " in prepareForSegue method, now i can see the nslog in onSave (the father functions is called) but the screen doesn't return and send the string back @Mr T

Answer (score -1):

try with GreenViewController.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<GreenViewDelegate> delegate;
```

and GreenViewController.m:

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    [_delegate onSave:self.NameText.text];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

ViewController.* seems to be OK

Comment: Unofrunately it doesn't work @disepulv
I really appreciate your help